# Akka: Trying to understand order of message delivery between Actors

Tags: java, scala, kotlin, concurrency, akka

I'm wondering why the messages are being printed in exactly the same order as in the code.

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter

data class Request(val name: String)

class Device : AbstractActor() {
    val log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().getSystem(), this);

    override fun createReceive(): Receive {
        return receiveBuilder().matchEquals("print") { x -> log.info("hello i'm a device") }
                .match(Request::class.java) { x -> log.info("A " + x.name) }
                .build()
    }

    companion object {
        fun props(): Props {
            return Props.create { Device() }
        }
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val system = ActorSystem.create("container")
    val deviceA = system.actorOf(Device.props())
    val deviceC = system.actorOf(Device.props())
    val deviceD = system.actorOf(Device.props())


    val deviceB = system.actorOf(Device.props())

    deviceA.tell(Request("first "), deviceB)
    deviceA.tell(Request("second"), deviceC)
    deviceA.tell(Request("third"), deviceD)



}
```

It prints out:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dvisualvm.id=32047598721041 -javaagent:/opt/intellij-idea-community/lib/idea_rt.jar=41737:/opt/intellij-idea-community/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/dell/akka-quickstart-java/target/classes:/home/dell/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.12/2.5.19/akka-actor_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.8/scala-library-2.12.8.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.3.3/config-1.3.3.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-java8-compat_2.12/0.8.0/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.8.0.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.20.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.20.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.20.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/dell/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.20.jar StuffKt
[INFO] [01/31/2019 18:43:16.058] [container-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://container/user/$a] A first 
[INFO] [01/31/2019 18:43:16.059] [container-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://container/user/$a] A second
[INFO] [01/31/2019 18:43:16.059] [container-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://container/user/$a] A third
```

I was expecting the order to be different sometimes from ("first second third"), but it keeps printing out that same order on every run.

Is my expectation incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation on message delivery order](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#discussion-message-ordering) states

> **The rule more specifically is that for a given pair of actors,
>   messages sent directly from the first to the second will not be
>   received out-of-order**. The word directly emphasizes that this
>   guarantee only applies when sending with the tell operator to the
>   final destination, not when employing mediators or other message
>   dissemination features (unless stated otherwise).

You are sending from the main method (outside of the actor system) to `deviceA`.

You are **not** sending from the `deviceB`, `deviceC`, or `deviceD` actors. Those are just being used as sender references, so that `deviceA` has [someone to reply to](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorRef.html#tell(msg:Any,sender:akka.actor.ActorRef):Unit).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Didn't realize there was such a big distinction between sending from actors vs sending from actor refs...

Comment: @NZ_21 The behavior would've been the same if you created an actor `deviceZ` and, within its receiver, performed your `tell` calls. They would still be received in the order of the invocations.

Comment: @NZ_21 The important thing is _where_ the message comes from, regardless whether that's within the actor system our out of it.

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting how the scope (actor system) decides where the message is coming from.   I've just started hakking, but I don't think it's super evident from the boilerplate code that how that's actually happening. It was a bit confusing to me initially since the second arg for ```tell()``` is ```sender```, but as you said, that's just a reference the receiver can reply to. It's not the "real" sender.

Comment: @NZ_21 Think about it like a standard Java `ExecutorService` with a single thread `B`. If you're in thread `A`, all your `Runnable` passed to `submit` will be ran in the order they were submitted. If you have another thread `B` calling `submit`, their tasks will potentially interleave with `A`'s.